# Getting nil from NSNumberformater numberFromString

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to format an amount from a .txt file coming in es_US locale(x,xxx.xx), to my current locale with is es_ES(x.xxx,xx). I would expect that [NSNumberFormater numberFromString] would just reformat the string, however and I'm only getting a nil value from this method.

I also tried another approach after checking the answers from here, but NSDecimalnumber does not work if the string has thousand separators, so if anybody could tell me what am I doing wrong please...

```
 - (void) setSaldo_sap:(NSString *)saldo_sap
 {
    NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [numFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [numFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"-¤#,##0.00"];

    //saldo_sap = @"         -324,234.55"
    NSString * tmpString = [saldo_sap stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSNumber *num = [numFormatter numberFromString:tmpString];
    NSDecimalNumber *tempNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:tmpString];  

    _saldo_sap = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:tempNumber];        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misinterpret the aim of NSNumberFormatter: it doesn't "reformat", it "formats" and "parses" a numbers formatted along the set rules. So if you have numbers coming in "es_US" locale but want to format them using "es_ES" you will need two NSNumberFormatters: one for each locale.

Parse the incoming number with "es_US" and format using "es_ES", simplifying a bit (I don't know those two locales and the exact format of your numbers so you may need to tweek it a bit):

```
NSString * tmpString = ...

NSNumberFormatter *usFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[usFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"es_US"] autorelease]];
[usFormatter setHasThousandSeparators: YES];

NSNumberFormatter *esFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[esFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"es_ES"] autorelease]];
[esFormatter setHasThousandSeparators: YES];

// this assignment looks also somewhat weird: is it an instance variable? 
// 'cause if it is and you assign an autoreleased string you'll have a bad pointer there
_saldo_sap = [esFormatter stringFromNumber: [usFormatter numberFromString: tmpString]];

// And unless you use ARC you leak your formatter on each call, so at the end
[usFormatter release];
[esFormatter release];
```

**EDIT**
If the input strings contain prefix/postfix characters, that may prevent NSNumberFormatter to work (it use usually pretty strict), use `setLenient:`:

"Sets whether the receiver will use heuristics to guess at the number which is intended by a string."

If you have more than one number to be converted, do not create the formatters for each number, this is just a waste of memory and cpu. Make them instance variables and reuse. It will be much clearer than just having one formatter and reconfiguring it between parsing one format and formatting in another.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *_saldo_sap = @"         -324234.55";
//NSString *_saldo_sap = @"         324,234.55";

NSString * tmpString = [_saldo_sap stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
//tmpString = @"-324,234.55"

NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *num = [numFormatter numberFromString:tmpString];

[numFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[numFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numFormatter setNegativeFormat:@"-¤#,##0.00"];

_saldo_sap = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:num];
```

Firstly, for getting NSNumber from NSString the string must be in correct readable format i.e. it must not include any characters like " , " as stated.
Secondly, you must first convert the string to NSNumber and then format it accordingly.

Comment: So is there any method or function in order to get rid of the thousand separators?, i.e.: _saldo_sap=@"    3,242.55" as it comes from the txt file, should be @"    3242.55" in order to be converted to NSNumber. Bear in mind that txt files come formatted as they are tailored in the different locales (countries), for example text from US and GB, comes with the comma thousand separator format, and ES, FR, etc... will come with dot separator for the thousands.

Comment: 'it must not include any characters like " , "' is plain wrong. NSNumberFormatter can very well cope not only with thousand separators but also with percent signs, currency etc. They just need to be configured appropriately: look at setHasThousandSeparators:, setThousandSeparator:. In fact NSNumberFormatter can cope with any format you can think of, even grouping sizes can be set!!! Read the API.